# Writing a apache camel test case but getting this error

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, junit5

am writing a camel route test case but am getting this issue,  have also included the camel route. Have debugged looks like the object is flowing through properly but on my assertion it seems to fail...

> java.lang.AssertionError:
> mock://seda:processMessage?blockWhenFull=true Received message count.
> Expected: <1> but was: <0>

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.camel.EndpointInject;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.spring.MockEndpoints;
import org.apache.camel.test.spring.junit5.CamelSpringBootTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.sams.pricing.prism.data.processor.model.CostIQRetail;
import com.sams.pricing.prism.data.processor.service.RulesEngineClient;
import com.sams.pricing.prism.data.processor.util.Endpoints;



@SpringBootTest
@CamelSpringBootTest
@MockEndpoints( Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT)
public class CamelRouteTests3  {


    

        @Autowired
        private ProducerTemplate template;

        @EndpointInject("mock:"+ Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT)
        private MockEndpoint mock;

        @Mock
        private RulesEngineClient rulesEngineClientMock;

    
    

    public CostIQRetail costIQObject() {

        CostIQRetail obj = new CostIQRetail();

        obj.setItemNbr(123);
        obj.setLocationNbr(4931);
        obj.setIsDcFlag(false) ;
        obj.setStatus("SUCCESS");
        obj.setOrderableCost(new BigDecimal((10.0)));
        obj.setWarehousePackCost(new BigDecimal(100.0));
        obj.setOrderablePrepaidCost(null) ;
        obj.setOrderableCollectCost(null) ;
        obj.setReasonCode("Markdown - category funded");
        obj.setEffectiveDate("2022-12-29");
        obj.setIsFutureEffectiveDate(false);
        obj.setCostType("WAREHOUSE PACK COST");
        obj.setSource("COST IQ");
        obj.setCreatedBy("lab1 account");
        obj.setCreatedByUserId("LB-cost-test");
        obj.setCreatedTs("2022-12-29T02:42:25.529Z");
        obj.setCurrentRetailPrice(new BigDecimal(55.0)) ;
        obj.setCurrentOrderableCost(null);
        obj.setCurrentWarehousePackCost(new BigDecimal((0.0)));
        obj.setCurrentOrderablePrepaidCost(null) ;
        obj.setCurrentOrderableCollectCost(null);
        obj.setMarginChange(new BigDecimal((-100.0)));
        obj.setOwedToClub(new BigDecimal((0.0))); 
        obj.setItemSourceId(3572924); 
        obj.setPriceDestId(701800);
        obj.setCategory(87);
        obj.setOrderableQty(null);
        obj.setOldMargin(new BigDecimal((100.0)));
        obj.setNewMargin(new BigDecimal(0.0));  

        return obj;
    }

    private String costIQPayloadString() throws JsonProcessingException
    {

         String key =  "{\"retailTypeReasonCode\":{\"retailTypeReasonCodeId\":{\"retailType\":\"BP\",\"retailReasonCode\":\"CC\"}},\"expirationDate\":null,\"customerRetailAmount\":0.0,\"auditMessage\":null,\"createdTimestamp\":null,\"clientID\":\"COST IQ\",\"rowNumber\":0,\"auditRecordTimestamp\":null,\"clubNumber\":4931,\"itemNumber\":123,\"effectiveDate\":\"2022-12-29\",\"submissionID\":null,\"retailAmount\":55.0,\"createdBy\":\"lab1 account\"}";
    //   String key2 = "{\"retailTypeReasonCode\":{\"retailTypeReasonCodeId\":{\"retailType\":\"BP\",\"retailReasonCode\":\"CC\"}},\"expirationDate\":null,\"customerRetailAmount\":0.0,\"auditMessage\":null,\"createdTimestamp\":null,\"clientID\":\"COST IQ\",\"rowNumber\":0,\"auditRecordTimestamp\":null,\"categoryId\":87,\"subCategoryId\":1,\"clubNumber\":4931,\"itemNumber\":123,\"effectiveDate\":\"2022-12-29\",\"submissionID\":null,\"retailAmount\":10.0,\"createdBy\":\"lab1 account\"}";
         return key;

//      CostIQPayloadTransformer transformer = new CostIQPayloadTransformer();
//      return transformer.payloadTransformer(costIQObject());
    }


    @Test
     void test() throws Exception {
        // Set up the mock endpoints
        mock.expectedBodiesReceived(costIQPayloadString());
        
        //getMockEndpoint( mock  +  Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT).expectedBodiesReceived(costIQPayloadString());


        //**need to properly mock and return this value
        Mockito.when(rulesEngineClientMock.validateRules((costIQObject()))).thenReturn(costIQObject());  //.thenR

        Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("appName", "costIQ");

        //   Send the test message to the SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT
        template.sendBodyAndHeaders(Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT, costIQObject(), headers);

        //System.out.println("here " +mock.());
        mock.assertIsSatisfied();


    
    }



}
```

(below is the camel route )

```
 ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    ExecutorService executorService =
        MoreExecutors.getExitingExecutorService(executor, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ThrottlingInflightRoutePolicy throttlingInflightRoutePolicy =
        new ThrottlingInflightRoutePolicy();
    throttlingInflightRoutePolicy.setMaxInflightExchanges(150);
    throttlingInflightRoutePolicy.setResumePercentOfMax(25);

    // Camel's error handler that will attempt to redeliver the message 3 times
    errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("seda:costIqDeadLetterChannel")
                    .maximumRedeliveries(3)
                    .redeliveryDelay(3000)
    );

    // SEDA Endpoint Stage Event Driven Architecture
    from(Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT)
        .messageHistory()
        // Route Name
        .routeId(Endpoints.SEDA_SEND_ENDPOINT)

        // multicast
        .multicast()
        .parallelProcessing() // create parallel threads

        // thread pool
        .threads()
        .executorService(executorService) // specific thread pool
        .log("Camel Route Started Message Processing : - ${body}")

        .choice()
        .when(PrismUtility.costIQPredicate)
        .circuitBreaker()
        .inheritErrorHandler(true)
        .bean(CostIQService.class, PrismConstants.CALCULATE_PRICE) // rules engine call
        .bean(
            CostIQPayloadTransformer.class,
            PrismConstants.PAYLOAD_TRANSFORMER) // payload transformer
        .to(
            Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT // consumer 1
            )
        .endCircuitBreaker()
        .endChoice()

        .log("Final :- ${body}")
        .end();
```

Edit :

I modified the class like below by adding "mock:" to my route but  is there a way to go around this? seems like it is not sending to the proper endpoint without me changing and adding the "mock:" value to where it is sending

Edit :

I added in this peice of code - to try to use adviceWith in my test class. I am calling the endpoint like so

```
    getMockEndpoint("mock:"+Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT).expectedBodiesReceived(costIQPayloadString());
```

But am getting the error

> Cannot advice routes as there are no routes

```
   @Test
    public void testReplaceFrom() throws Exception {
        AdviceWith.adviceWith(context, Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT, a -> {
            a.mockEndpoints("mock:"+Endpoints.SEDA_PROCESS_ENDPOINT);
        });
        }
```

Comment: You could use the `template.sendBody` method

Comment: I have a predicate checking headers so I need to send headers, what difference is there between template.sendBody and         template.sendBodyAndHeaders? Issue seems to be that when I mock the endpoint with "mock:" in test class it does not puck up the .to() endpoint - I manually added the "mock:" into the route as well and it worked but I am sure this is not the proper way..

Comment: Believe I may need to use Advice with not sure how to implement...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with route advice. Note that you probably will need to do some cleanup after your test to reset the data!

A bit older code in kotlin but should get the idea:

```
@SpringBootTest
class YourTest {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var camelContext: CamelContext

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var template: ProducerTemplate

    // No MockEndpoints

    ...

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    private fun configureMockEndpoint() {
        AdviceWith.adviceWith(
            camelContext,
            "yourRouteId"
        ) { adviceWithRouteBuilder: AdviceWithRouteBuilder ->
            adviceWithRouteBuilder.replaceFromWith("direct:test")
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun yourTest() {
        configureMockEndpoint()
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:test", "Your headers", """
            your content
        """.trimIndent())
        // asserts
        // cleanups
    }

}
```

Comment: is"yourrouteID" the .from() or .to in your camel route? I want to send to the actual .from() but want the .from() redirected to the mock I am gonna make

Comment: (updated the question with new edit